# Making many new columns based on .SD cols in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I know there must be a good way to do this with data.table, but I'm having trouble figuring it out. I want to create a bunch of new columns that are based on arithmetic of current columns.

For example, I have a data.table with columns like "a_num, a_denom, b_num, b_denom..." and I'd like do something like:

```
DT[,a_ratio := a_num / a_denom]
```

except that I want to do that for a, b, c, d, ... z

I think the answer should be something like:

```
DT[, paste0(.SD, '_ratio') := paste0(.SD, '_num') / paste0(.SD, '_denom'), .SDcols = c('a', 'b', 'c')]
```

but that doesn't seem to work for me at all.

Comment: what if you just do: `DT[,endsWith(names(DT),"num")]/DT[,endsWith(names(DT),"denom")]`??

Comment: you're probably better off reshaping your data first, unless the data set is large. anyway, I think the key problem of your approach are that: .SD is not a character vector, it's a data.table, whereas it seems you want to use a character vector to loop over a/b/c. in your case I would use a for loop; you'll also benefit from using `get`

Comment: As mentioned by MichaelChirico, prob DT[,(paste0(letters,’_ratio’)):=lapply(letters,function(x)get(paste0(x,’_num’))/get(paste0(x,’_denom’)))]

Comment: Wow I'm struggling, I'm not sure how to pick an answer but thanks guys! 

Chinsoon12's answer does seem best to me and does work!

Comment: Fyi, there's a feature request posted for this: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/795 (I think reshaping as Michael suggested is the way to go, fwiw.)